# Does a power-supply for a computer typically have temperature modulated fan control?

Tags: fan, noise

In other words:  if I cool it using a large slow quiet fan, will it shut up, or do I need to build my own temperature control circuit?

Comment: Explain your question: You want to remove the cooling system that your computer already has, and use a fan that you provide?
If so, why do you mention power supply on question title? And, most important question, qhy do you want to do it?

Comment: It depends. Modern power supplies do this. Others even shut it off completely when load is at a minimum. Replace the fan with a similar spec one.

Comment: The last thing I want is a fire, but ideally I may want to go with a large powerful yet quiet system fan, and remove the power supply and CPU fan.

Comment: I could make an arduino backup circuit to turn backup fans on in this case.   I can measure the psu and CPU temp now, then make sure it stays at that level or lower when I install the large quiet fan.  If it gets hot, I can turn on the extra fans.